# Looping through string array by pointer

Tags: c++

I am trying to return array of strings from a function and loop throught it:

```
string* fetchArray()
{
    string myArray[10] = { "0" };
    myArray[9] = { "End" };
    return myArray;
};

int main()
{
    string* fetchedArray = fetchArray();

    while (*fetchedArray != "End")
    {
        cout << *fetchedArray << endl;
        fetchedArray++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am doing something wrong. This results in runtime error. I can see while I debug that the *fetchedArray is empty after function call, which could mean that the function did not return what I was expecting. I was at least  expecting that the first element of the array will be correct.

Error:

> Exception thrown at 0x54AA40D5 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Test.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Usually, I would use vector in this situation, but I wanted to test this behaviour.

Comment: Don't return the address of a local variable from a function. Such a return value is meaningless and must never be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return a pointer to a *local variable*. The variable `myArray` is like all other local variables, and will go out of scope once the function it was defined in returns. That will leave you with a stray pointer to data that no longer exists and lead to *undefined behavior*.

---

As an interesting side-note: Just *having* the stray pointer is in itself not UB, but attempting to dereference the pointer is what leads to the UB. So you *can* return a pointer to a local variable, as long as you don't use it (which is kind of pointless).

Comment: Cool! Hm, what would then be the solution if I want to return this array? (without the array being stored in the function, or using global variable) Is there any?

Comment: @omegasbk If you don't want to make it `static` or global, or change to use a `std::vector` or `std::array` (which is of course the "proper" solution) the only solution is to dynamically allocate the memory of the heap and return that pointer.

Comment: @omegasbk The solution would be to use `std::vector<std::string>` and return that by value.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning address of local variable, which goes out of scope after the return from call to `fetchArray`.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable. Local variables get destroyed at the end of the function they're declared in. Thus you end up with a dangling pointer. Dereferencing that causes undefined behavior.